# Adding an object to an ArrayList that takes another object as a param

Tags: java, object, arraylist, parameters, constructor

Hey everyone I'm trying to brush up on my java knowledge as I have not coded in java in a while. I am working on this store project that has three class. 1.Product 2.InventoryItem & 3.Store

Product class requires a String for the name and a double for the cost. There are accessor and mutator methods for setting and retrieving the data.

```
public class Product {
//fields
private String productName;
private double cost;

/**
 * Contructor
 *
 * @param productName
 * @param cost
 */
public Product(String productName, double cost){
   this.productName = productName;
   this.cost = cost;
}
...
```

The InventoryItem class adds on a quantity along side the info of product. This will be made clear as to why with the Store class.
I would like to pass a new Product Object as a parameter in the constructor to make adding all the info into an ArrayList easier later. As above I have created set and get methods for name,cost, and quantity.

```
public class InventoryItem {
//fields
private Product productObject;
private int quantity;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param quantity
 */
public InventoryItem(new Product, int quantity) {

    this.quantity = quantity;
}

/**
 * Method to set new name for product in inventory
 *
 * @param newProductName
 */
public void setProductName(String newProductName) {
    productObject.setProductName(newProductName);
}
...
```

I would also like to know how I would go about using Products methods once I figure out how to pass the Object as an argument.

When trying to pre-populate my ArrayList with InventotyItems I started to get an error. This is being done in my Store class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store {
//fields
private String storeName;
private String location;
private ArrayList<InventoryItem> itemList;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Store(String storeName, String location){
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.location = location;
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
}

/**
 * Method to prepopulate a list of items the store will be selling
 */
private void setItemList(){
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Bananas", 1.50)20));
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Canned Beans", 2.00)15));
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Easy-Mac", 2.50)15));
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Oranges", .50)25));
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Cereal", 3.00)10):);
   itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product("Milk", 4.00)10));

}
```

}

Rather then changing my parameters in InventoryItem

```
itemList.add(newInventoryItem("Bananas", 1.50, 20));
```

I would like to figure out how to pass new Product as shown above in the block of code from the Store class.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `new Product("Bananas", 1.50)20)` are you forgetting commas or is this just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Im sorry the last part of my question is confusing. When i said "as shown above" I meant how i prepopulated the ArrayList in the block of code above. I would like to use that method to create new Inventory Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. A comma is missing when you instantiate your `InventoryItem`.

Replace

```
new InventoryItem(new Product("Bananas", 1.50)20)
```

With

```
new InventoryItem(new Product("Bananas", 1.50), 20)
```

Comment: Thank you for the syntax help with that. I would have most definitely missed that comma. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `InventoryItem` constructor. the constructor should get paramaters like `(Product product)` , not with new keyword

```
public InventoryItem(Product product, int quantity) {

    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter Inventory Item constructor to pass the data like that.

```
public class InventoryItem {
//fields
private Product productObject;
private int quantity;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param quantity
 */
public InventoryItem(new Product, int quantity) {

    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public InventoryItem(String productName, double cost, int quantity) {
    this.productObject = new Product(productName,cost);
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

/**
 * Method to set new name for product in inventory
 *
 * @param newProductName
 */
public void setProductName(String newProductName) {
    productObject.setProductName(newProductName);
}
```

Comment: not sure if an overloaded constructor would help when I prepopulate the ArrayList like `itemList.add(new InventoryItem(new Product(String, double), int));` @Arun

Comment: if you want to populate the object like `itemList.add(newInventoryItem("Bananas", 1.50, 20));` as mentioned in the question this is to be used.